# Android split ActionBar - Change layout of icons

Tags: android, split, android-actionbar

OK, this question is quick, how can I change the layout positioning of actionbar icons in a split actionbar?

In my app they are always placed evenly accross all the width of the bottom actionbar, but I'd like to be able to align some to the right, others to the left.

How should I approach this?

Thank you very much in advance :)

PS: I am using ActionBarSherlock, in case it is relevant.

---

***Edit:***

This is one of my app screens:

[image: Buttons placed evenly]

This is how I would like it to look now:

[image: Buttons ideally placed to the right]

And this is how I would like it to look with three buttons:

[image: 3 Buttons ideally placed]

---

I have added the items via menu.xml files:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/AB_add"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/menu_add_item_to_shopping_list">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/AB_delete"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/menu_delete_item_from_shopping_list">
    </item>
</menu>
```

And instantiated them via onCreateOptionsMenu()

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();

            inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_recipe_detail, menu);
    }
```

Comment: I looked for it in the Android reference and googled for it without luck. Also I checked all the possible attributes for a menu item, and didn't find any related to positioning. I tried with custom actionViews, but I was only able to change the contents of the button, not its positioning (but I might have done it wrong!). Thank you

Comment: please post an image of what you have now, how you would like it to be (use photoshop) and the code you use now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem can be solved by a ugly way ,hope this helps u

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_write1"
        android:icon="@drawable/statusnewactivity_send_light"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="reply1"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/space1"
        android:checkable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/space2"
        android:checkable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_write2"
        android:icon="@drawable/statusnewactivity_send_light"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="reply2"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_write3"
        android:icon="@drawable/statusnewactivity_send_light"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="reply3"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this isn't achievable using standard Android ActionBar code or ActionBarSherlock. I have faced a similar problem and found the only way of dealing with it is using a custom LinearLayout that just resembles an ActionBar.

The split ActionBar will look very different depending on the device you use. On a phone ("narrow" screen) it will be shown on the bottom as in your screen. However, in landscape mode or on tablets it will not be split at all. This should also influence your decision whether you want to do the custom work or not.

Comment: Thanks André. That's what I feared most. I'll keep the question open for some time though, in case anyone proposes something else.